# Core 2.2 Compare(name()) fails when comparison is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I am using Razor pages for a registration form. I am using model binding to bind the form to page model properties. I am using the Compare(nameof()) data annotation to check the password fields. When the two password fields are matching, the comparison still fails and the ModelState.IsValid returns false. The validation summary says "Could not find a property named txtPassword"

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="col-12">
    <label asp-for="ddlInstitution"></label>
    <select asp-for="ddlInstitution" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)Model.Institutions)">
    </select>
    <div>If your institution is not listed please email the Principal Investigator to request that
        it be added.</div>
</div>
<p />
<div class="row gtr-uniform">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <label asp-for="txtFirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="txtFirstName" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="txtFirstName" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <label asp-for="txtLastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="txtLastName" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="txtLastName" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p/>
<div class="col-12">
    <label asp-for="txtEmailAddress"></label>
    <input asp-for="txtEmailAddress" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
    <span asp-validation-for="txtEmailAddress" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
</div>
</p>
<div class="row gtr-uniform">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <label asp-for="txtTitle"></label>
        <input asp-for="txtTitle" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="txtTitle" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <label asp-for="txtDepartment"></label>
        <input asp-for="txtDepartment" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="txtDepartment" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</p>
<div class="row gtr-uniform">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <label asp-for="txtPassword"></label>
        <input name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" type="password" asp-for="txtPassword" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="txtPassword" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
        <label asp-for="txtConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input type="password" asp-for="txtConfirmPassword" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        <span asp-validation-for="txtConfirmPassword" class="text-danger" style="color: red"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p/>
<div class="col-12">
    <input type="submit" class="button fit"/>
</div>
```

Here is my PageModel Binding. Everything seems correct.

```
    [BindProperty, Required, Display(Name = "Institution Name")]
    public string ddlInstitution {get; set;}

    [BindProperty, Required, Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string txtFirstName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required, Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string txtLastName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required, EmailAddress, Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string txtEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Institutions { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required, MinLength(2), Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string txtTitle { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required, MinLength(3), Display(Name = "Department")]
    public string txtDepartment { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required, MinLength(8), MaxLength(16), Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string txtPassword { get; set; }

    [BindProperty, Required, MinLength(8), MaxLength(16), Compare(nameof(txtPassword), ErrorMessage = "Your passwords do not match."),  Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    public string txtConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string Color {get; set;}
```

I am now officially at the "pulling my hair out" stage. Everything is correct. I appreciate any advice anyone could offer.

Answer (score 0):

Upon googling this further, it appears this is a bug in Core 2.2, which will be fixed in Core 3. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4895. Would appreciate an expert confirming.